# mura cms new site: preview not displaying

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I have set up a new site on mura cms 5.4 and gave it the domain localhost but nothing gets displayed in the preview.it is  a site in construction and so assigned it localhost as the domain.
why doesnt it allow me to preview the changes? 
it keeps giving me page cannot be displayed.
i have tried getting to it from the link that appears on the top of the page

please help. greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I advice to upgrade to the latest version of Mura (version 6) and see if the issue still occures. Since Mura 5.4 is an old version, there is a big chance the issue is fixed meanwhile.

It's very easy and save to upgrade Mura. http://docs.getmura.com/installation-set-up/upgrading-mura/